# Is it possible to use LuaInterface in Mono/Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mono, luainterface

LuaInterface uses two .dlls: **lua51** and **luanet**.

While being able to rebuild lua51 to liblua5.1.dylib (and code actually found all necessary entry points) im completely stuck with **luanet.dll**.

Does anyone have an idea how to build it on Mac OS or if I have to avoid using it entirely (at cost of losing such stuff as ObjectTranslator and MetaFunctions)?

*I already know that there are alternatives like http://github.com/jsimmons/LuaSharp.*

Comment: All I have is an error: `DllNotFoundException: luanet
LuaInterface.ObjectTranslator.createBaseClassMetatable (IntPtr luaState) (at Assets/LuaInterface/ObjectTranslator.cs:87)
LuaInterface.ObjectTranslator..ctor (LuaInterface.Lua interpreter, IntPtr luaState) (at Assets/LuaInterface/ObjectTranslator.cs:48)
LuaInterface.Lua..ctor () (at Assets/LuaInterface/Lua.cs:86)
LuaInterfaceTest..ctor ()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your DllMap to tell it that luanet.dll should be looked for at lua51.dylib

http://www.mono-project.com/Config_DllMap